# Extension's form of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

If $M$ is a smooth manifold and $W$ is a smooth vector field defined on an embedded submanifold $S$ of $M$, I know that we can extend $W$ all over $M$ but my question is:
any extension of $W$ is of the form $\sum\rho_\alpha W_\alpha$ with $\{\rho_\alpha\}$ a partition of unity subordinated to an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $M$ and $W_\alpha=W|_{U_\alpha}$ on $\{U_\alpha\cap S\neq\emptyset$}?

Thanks for all help me.

Edit: closed embedding submanifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t extend to all of $M$ without some extra conditions like that the embedded submanifold is closed.

Comment: Oh, right, closed. But my question is if any extension has that form (partition of unity and so on.